# asp http POST Read Data

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, iphone

I am POSTING some data from an IPhone application want want to be able to read this data from the server. I have never created a http post server before and i am unsure which is the best way to read this data.

This is the IPhone Code posting the data:

```
/*
  turning the image into a NSData object
  getting the image back out of the UIImageView
  setting the quality to 90
 */

 NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image.image, 0.9);
 // setting up the URL to post to
 NSString *urlString = @"http://192.168.56.129/Post/default.aspx";

 // setting up the request object now
 NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
 [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
 [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

 /*
  add some header info now
  we always need a boundary when we post a file
  also we need to set the content type

  You might want to generate a random boundary.. this is just the same 
  as my output from wireshark on a valid html post
 */
 NSString *boundary = [NSString stringWithString:@"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449"];
 NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
 [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

 /*
  now lets create the body of the post
 */
 NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
 [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]; 
 [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\"ipodfile.jpg\"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
 [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
 [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
 [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
 // setting the body of the post to the reqeust
 [request setHTTPBody:body];

 // now lets make the connection to the web
 NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
 NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

 NSLog(returnString);
```

How would I read this when it hits my server? I would like to use .Net, C-Sharp, can you give me some examples of how I would achieve this.

What my goal is, to grab the picture data taken and save into a SQL Server table as binary data.

Thanks Guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Used the following code to read this data:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[Request.ContentLength];
using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(Request.InputStream))
br.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
```

Answer (score 0):

Look into asp.net generic handlers. Here's a tutorial I found:

http://dotnetperls.com/ashx-handler